# Login_hint for google signin in android

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I am trying to add a login_hint parameter to google signIn android integration.
Basically I want to pre-populate the email field on signin page with the value which the user entered on my application similar to this : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDSignIn#-signinwithpresentingviewcontroller:hint:completion:

Right now I create an intent, add email as an extra to it and start the activity, but that doesn't seem to be working :

```
val signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient?.signInIntent
signInIntent?.putExtra("email", userEnteredEmail)
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
```

Is there anyways to populate this login_hint in android as well?